# script for copying a column to another column of different table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

SQL command not properly ended - error is showing while I run below code. I want to copy all values  from Process column of table T_DOC to Process column of T_CHARACTERISTICS. Now Process column in `T_CHARACTERISTICS` is `NULL`.  (Except this column all other columns of `T_CHARACTERISTICS` is having values)  Thanks in advance

```
UPDATE T_CHARACTERISTICS 
SET T_CHARACTERISTICS.PROCESS = T_DOC.PROCESS
FROM T_CHARACTERISTICS  
JOIN  T_DOC ON T_CHARACTERISTICS.ID = T_DOC.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not proper Oracle syntax.  Here is one method:

```
UPDATE T_CHARACTERISTICS c
    SET PROCESS = (SELECT d.PROCESS
                   FROM T_DOC d
                   WHERE c.ID = d.ID
                  )
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM T_DOC d
                  WHERE c.ID = d.ID
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support update joins, but we can use a correlated subquery instead:

```
UPDATE T_CHARACTERISTICS t1
SET PROCESS = (SELECT t2.PROCESS FROM T_DOC t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID);
```